# Process is not completing even after putting the waitFor function

Tags: java

i am new to this Process Thing in java and i am having a problem with this shell command that i want to run in java.
I have this file with a large set of data in it and i want to convert it using XSL.
The command is working fine if run on cmd.exe but is not working in java code.
I have used the process wait too but still there is no output. Please help.
Thanks

Small fragment of code

```
    String c="java -Xmx1g -jar c:\\temp\\FileConverter.jar xmlTransform title \"Data\" root \"c:\\temp\\\" src \"c:\\temp\\input.xml\" xsl \"converter.xsl\" xsl:MEMBER_CODE \"111\" xsl:MEMBER_NAME \"ABC\" xsl:MEMBER_PASSWORD \"abc\" dst \"c:\\temp\\dummy.xml\" src-error \"c:\\temp\\error\"";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
     try {
        Process proc = rt.exec(c);
        synchronized (proc) {
             proc.wait(10000);
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You are using the `wait()` method from `Object`. You should use `Process#waitFor()`.

Comment: I tried that too but the process is running even faster with nothing in the output folder.

Comment: That points to that your process is'nt running anyway. Probably the arg for exec() is wrong. Read here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Comment: I guess that could be the problem but if the same command i run on cmd, it works fine with the desirable output.

Comment: Ok, but `cmd.exe` and `Runtime.exec()` do not work the same way.

Comment: I have tried another command,which is converting csv to xml, from the same java code and its working fine. The difference between the two cases is that the xml in the first case is huge. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Got it solved. The problem with the string that is being entered. Thank you so much for your time.